# get full client details in client

Tags: php

I want to get full details of a client who visits my site. I know I can get his/her ip by $_SERVER but I want to know where exactly his/her ip is reserved by. For example, I want to know which university visited my website. I used http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm but it just tells city, country and another things but it doesn't show what I need.
Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being realistic, you might as well use a service such as Google Analytics - they'll be able (where possible) to tell you the origin domain which is about as accurate as you're likely to get. (In many instances, you won't be able to obtain even something this useful.)

Alternatively, if you require this in something approaching real-time, you'll could attempt to obtain the reverse name lookup of the IP address, etc. or use one of the many IP to location based services available.

However, I wouldn't labour under the illusion that you'll be able to discover who's browsing your website in a reliable and meaningful way at the level of detail you seem to believe is possible.

Comment: Thanx for you reply. Could you tell me more about Google Analytics !? I couldn't find anything to help me. thanx.

Comment: I checked google analytics but it doesn't give me visitor's information that I need. I need client's provider, city and country so I can check which university checked my website. Does anybody have any idea how to do it? I found a website called ws.arin.net but it doesn't provide any scripts to do this. You have to get the whole page and tokenize it to get your data.

Comment: @Ali Bozorgkhan - Even with one of the commercial IP to location services, you won't be able to get data at that level with any degree of accuracy. As I said "I wouldn't labour under the illusion that you'll be able to discover who's browsing your website in a reliable and meaningful way at the level of detail you seem to believe is possible."

Comment: thanx middaparka ;) it really helped.